# Testing out angular-ui-bootstrap-rails toggling scope vars not working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not truly sure what is going on here, but when I click the button to disable the first item in the accordian, it just does nothing.  I meant this to be a test, so the code was stolen directly from [here (scroll down to the Accordion example)](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap).  This appears to work in the example, but not on my particular Rails application. However, the rest of the accordian behavior appears to work.  I didn't see any errors sent to the JavaScript console, either...

Here is the code I think might be relevant:

#### Gemfile (only a portion of it)

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# CSS framework
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
# JavaScript framework
gem 'angularjs-rails', '~> 1.3.10'
# Get rid of the jQuery dependency by using Angular-ui.
gem 'angular-ui-bootstrap-rails', '~> 0.9.0'
```

#### /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require angular
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-ui-bootstrap-tpls
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'

    },
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'

    }

  ];

  $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
    $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);

  };

  $scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    isFirstDisabled: false
  };

});
```

#### /app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.checkbox {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

#### /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='ui.bootstrap.demo'>
<head>
  <title>Site Title</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%# <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%# <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

#### /app/views/pages/home.html.erb

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.open = !status.open">Toggle last panel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.isFirstDisabled = !status.isFirstDisabled">Enable / Disable first panel</button>
  </p>

  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
    Open only one at a time
  </label>
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
  <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
  This content is straight in the template.
  </accordion-group>
  <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
  {{group.content}}
  </accordion-group>
  <accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
  <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
  </accordion-group>
  <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
  <accordion-heading>
  I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
  </accordion-heading>
  This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
  </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is, since the `is-open` attribute works on the last accordion group, and that behavior works similarly, is it something to do with `is-disabled` not being recognized properly by Angular-ui or something?

Comment: I still haven't made any progress on this error.  Is anyone wise-up to what might be causing this?

Comment: This issue self-resolved after I got my assets to correctly precompile (I ended up pulling out the gems and including all of my front-end dependencies using Bower).  I'm still interested in knowing why this might not have been working, however...